# Ajax request using Selenium in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape a website that loads hidden data when you scroll to the bottom of the page.
So far i have loaded the data by scrolling to the end of the page through selenium by using  actions.send_keys(Keys.END).
Is there a way to load the whole data of the page, when the page is loaded.

Comment: you can try to resize window at start and browser will have to load all data - but  without option `headless` selenium may not create window bigger than desktop. And you don't know how big window you need - 5 000px, 10 000px  or more.

Comment: if you know url which is used to load data then you can use module `requests` or `urllib.request` to get this data and you don't need `Selenium`. Pages mostly send data as JSON which can be easily converted to Python's dictionary and you can easily find elements in dictionary.

Comment: It is a javascript page.

Comment: if page use JavaScript to load data from some URL and you know this URL then you can use `requests` or `urllib.request` to get it. I offen use DevTool in Chrome/Firefox to see all requests from browser to server and I find request which loads data and then I use `requests` to get data.